# How can I rewrite a line in a WordPress plugin that contains the deprecated 'create_function' method to maintain PHP 8.0 compatibility?

Tags: php, wordpress, deprecated, php-8

I'm trying to maintain compatibility of a crucial WordPress plugin ([jQuery Vertical Accordion Menu](http://www.designchemical.com/blog/index.php/wordpress-plugins/wordpress-plugin-jquery-vertical-accordion-menu-widget/)) on my site.

There's one line in the plugin code that breaks the site with PHP 8.0:

```
add_action('widgets_init', create_function('', 'return register_widget("dc_jqaccordion_widget");'));
```

The problem is that the `create_function()` method [has been removed from PHP 8.0](https://lindevs.com/function-create_function-has-been-removed-in-php-8-0/) due to it being based on the `eval()` function which has security issues. Apparently, there's a way to rewrite this line to use an anonymous function instead of calling `create_function()`, but I don't know PHP.

How can I re-write this line to maintain functionality, but avoid using the `create_function` method?

Comment: Does this help? https://lindevs.com/function-create_function-has-been-removed-in-php-8-0/

Comment: If you don't know _any_ PHP, then go find someone who does and buy them a beer to do this for you. If you know _some_ PHP, or even just some programming in general, then [there's documentation on anonymous functions here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php) and what you've got there is about the simplest case possible.